# Foundation align column right when using flex grid (not xy grid)

Tags: zurb-foundation

```
<div class="row align-middle">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <div></div>
        </div>

        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <div></div>
        </div>

        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <div>I want to be on the right edge of the parent .row</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have the above.

I want the `div` that's in the third `.columns` `div` to be aligned to the right (so that it would look the same as if I put `text-align: center` on the third `.columns` `div`).

I know a way to do so - by putting another `.row` div inside that column and giving that `.row` another class of `align-right` and putting then another `.columns` inside of that row - but this would result in an unnecessary amount of HTML and I assume Foundation must have provided me a way (another CSS class that I can't find in the docs) of achieving my goal without further HTML than is above.

How do I do this? Or do I have to put another row and column inside that third column?

`.columns` doesn't have `display: flex` so I can't put `align-right` on the column - won't work. Or are `.columns` meant to have `display:flex` and I'm just experiencing a bug or otherwise an issue I've possibly created somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the 6.5 version of foundation, then the following replacements in code would do what you expect

```
<div class="grid-x">
    <div class="small-4 cell">
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-4 cell">
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-4 cell">
        <div>I want to be on the right edge of the parent .row</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But if you really don't want to use the `grid-xy` classes, then you can keep your code and use instead foundation 5.5. I hope this helps!